# Checking if a value has more than 3 decimal places in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

As the title states I am trying to check if a value had greater than 3 decimal places. This is the first time that I have had to deal with angularjs and I am not certain how to check that. I have check if value is whole number, greater than 0, etc.. But I am uncertain on the decimal places. Here is a snippet of my whole number check. Any suggestions on how I could do the check for the decimals would be greatly appreciated. I am trying to show a error message if the user goes over 3 decimals places.

Whole number example:

```
(mySubmittedOrder && myQuantity % 1 ===0)
```

Comment: What about split by yoyr decimal separator and use a function like: var countDecimals = function (value) {
if(Math.floor(value) === value) return 0;
return value.toString().split(".")[1].length || 0;
}

Answer (score 1):

```
var num1 = 1.123;

  function decimalCount(num){
    var numStr = String(num);
    // String Contains Decimal
    if (numStr.includes('.')) {
      return numStr.split('.')[1].length;
    };
    // String Does Not Contain Decimal
    return 0;
  }

  var decimalNumber = decimalCount(num1);

  if(decimalNumber == 3){
    console.log("3 decimals");
  }else{
    console.log("Not 3 decimals");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery :

```
$filter('number')(number, fractionSize)
```

or
Angular:

```
<span id='number-default'>{{val | number}}</span><br>
```